# Creating a JSON string from a jagged array in javascript efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a jagged array where the series of column names is contained in the first row of the array and the data is contained in subsequent rows. I need to convert this into a Json string containing a series of objects with property names extracted from the first row.

As an example if I have:

```
var arr = [["Age", "Class", "Group"], ["24", "C", "Prod"], ["25", "A", "Dev"], ["26", "B", "Test"]];
```

I need to end up with:

```
[
  {
    "Age": "24",
    "Class": "C",
    "Group": "Prod"
  },
  {
    "Age": "25",
    "Class": "A",
    "Group": "Dev"
  },
  {
    "Age": "26",
    "Class": "B",
    "Group": "Test"
  }
]
```

and I have written some code to do this:

```
var arr = [["Age", "Class", "Group"], ["24", "C", "Prod"], ["25", "A", "Dev"], ["26", "B", "Test"]];

var headings = arr[0]; /* Headings always contained in the first row*/
arr.shift(); /* Remove the first row of the array */

/* Create JSON string by iterating through each nested array and each of their respective values */
var jason = "[";
arr.forEach(function (x, y) {
  jason += "{";
  x.forEach(function (i, j) {
    jason += "\"" + headings[j] + "\":\"" + i + "\"";
    if (j < (x.length - 1)) {
      jason += ",";
    }
  })
  jason += "}";
  if (y < (x.length - 1)) {
    jason += ",";
  }
});
jason += "]";

console.log(jason);
```

I am trying to create a bigger dataset to test it on but I was hoping someone who knows a bit more about javascript than I do could help me determine if there is a more efficient way to do it.

For example, I have iterated through the jagged array using `arr.forEach` whereas I could have used a sequential for loop. Are there any performance concerns that I need to consider?

I should note that the length of each array in the jagged array is always the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `map` alongside `reduce`.

We know that the first element of `arr` are the keys, so we can `shift` that out, then `map` each of the other elements and `reduce` them to objects:

```js
const arr = [["Age", "Class", "Group"], ["24", "C", "Prod"], ["25", "A", "Dev"], ["26", "B", "Test"]];

const keys = arr.shift()

const out = arr.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, el, i) => (a[keys[i]] = el, a), {}))
console.log(out)
```